# Ошибка boost beast boost::Beast error The WebSocket frame payload was not valid utf8

Tags: c++, websocket, boost, boost.asio

При попытке асинхронного чтения в callbeack передается ошибка, при выводе сообщения о которой печатается следующая строка:

> boost::Beast error The WebSocket frame payload was not valid utf8

Как исправить эту проблему? Я передаю бинарные данные, мне не нужно кодировать их в utf8. В крайнем случае подскажите как сделать сообщения валидными на стороне клиента.

Ниже код клиента, в этом коде, с помощью операции `write` отправляются 2 сообщения, при этом первое принимается, а на втором вылетает ошибка. В качестве сообщения сереализуются `protobuf` классы. За исключением отправки сообщений, код полностью взят из примера.

```
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/connect.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "OrderManagement.grpc.pb.h"
namespace beast = boost::beast;      
namespace http = beast::http;          
namespace websocket = beast::websocket; 
namespace net = boost::asio;        
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;     

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {

        std::string host = "127.0.0.1";
        std::string port = "8000";
        net::io_context ioc;
        tcp::resolver resolver{ioc};
        websocket::stream<tcp::socket> ws{ioc};
        auto const results = resolver.resolve(host, port);
        auto ep = net::connect(ws.next_layer(), results);
        host += ':' + port;
        ws.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
                [](websocket::request_type& req)
                {
                    req.set(http::field::user_agent,
                            std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                            " websocket-client-coro");
                }));
        
        ws.handshake(host, "/");
        MailTaxi::DriverIdentification identification;
        identification.set_driverid(1);
        identification.set_token("1111111111");
        MailTaxi::Coordinate coordinate;
        coordinate.set_latitude(56.211);
        coordinate.set_longitude(123.21413);
        std::string text("1");
        text[0] = 0x01;
        // Send the message
        ws.write(net::buffer(text + identification.SerializeAsString()));


        int test = 1;
        while (test) {
            std::cin >> test;
            ws.write(net::buffer(text + coordinate.SerializeAsString()));
        }
        ws.close(websocket::close_code::normal);
    }

    catch(std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Минимальный пример не помешает. На вскидку у вас либо неверно хидер устанавливается, либо не верная длина сообщения (к примеру вы просто взяли длину строки где символ имеет два байта и передали его как Content-Length)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, добавил прмиер

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для передачи бинарных данных сокет необходимо предварительно перевести в режим передачи бинарных данных вызвав `ws.binary(true);`